# IF weeknumber <= "53" And weeknumber >= "1" wont work under 6, 7, 8, 9

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Function wknumber(weeknumber)
Do
weeknumber = InputBox("Week number:", "Week Selection")
If weeknumber = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "User Canceled!!!"
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    End
Else
    If weeknumber <= "53" And weeknumber >= "1" Then
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Your week is not among 1-52, retry with a valid week and use only numeric entries!!!", vbOKOnly, "Week Validation")
      ThisWorkbook.Close
        End
    End If
End If
Loop Until IsNumeric(weeknumber)
End Function
```

It's a pop out box that input week has to be under 53 and grater than 1, but the numbers 6, 7, 8, 9, won't work don't know why. Is there something else you guys see?

Comment: Convert it to a number first: `If CInt(weeknumber) <= 53 And CInt(weeknumber) >= 1 Then`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hi Johnny, that fixed it thanks! Just wonder, why does the all the number worked but those ones? also what I'm doing converting to number? Can you give me a lil explanation on this? pls. Thank you so much

Comment: @Ron actually OP is comparing strings (so "6" _is_ greater than "53") and expecting the comparison to be numeric

Comment: @chrisneilsen <<hand slapping forehead>> Of course, that's right. I will delete my comment.

Comment: Similarly, "seven" < "eight" is FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're comparing strings, not numbers. VBA can do this  but I believe just compares the ascii value of the first character, so "500 < "60" will return true because ascii value of "5" is less than the ascii value of "6". That's why your 6-9 tests are failing.

What you should do is attempt to convert the string input to a `Long` and compare that with your limits.

If you want to keep the `Do ... Loop` structure then the code would look a bit like below. Note: you'd need additional checks if, for example, you wanted to eliminate decimals or other types of numbers being entered:

```
Dim weekString As String
Dim weekNumber As Long

Do
    weekString = InputBox("Week number:", "Week Selection")
    
    'Check for an empty string.
    If weekString = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled."
        'do tasks.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check for a numeric
    weekNumber = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    weekNumber = CLng(weekString)
    On Error Goto 0
    If weekNumber = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Week number must be a number."
    'Check within range.
    ElseIf weekNumber < 1 Or weekNumber > 52 Then
        MsgBox "Week number must be between 1 and 52."
    End If
    
Loop While weekNumber < 1 Or weekNumber > 52

MsgBox "Week " & weekNumber & " selected."
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to numeric using *Val*, and no loop is needed:

```vb
Private Function wknumber(weeknumber)

    Dim Success As Boolean

    weeknumber = InputBox("Week number:", "Week Selection")
    If weeknumber = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "User Canceled."
    Else
        If Val(weeknumber) >= 1 And Val(weeknumber) <= 53 Then
            Success = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Your week is not among 1-52, retry with a valid week and use only numeric entries", vbOKOnly, "Week Validation"
        End If
    End If

    If Not Success Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        End
    End If

End Function
```